# Findbugs: Howto ignore Priority 2 and 3 warnings?

Tags: findbugs

i like to configure Findsbug-Filter to ignore some priority 2 and 3 warnings.

Something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FindBugsFilters>
    <Match>      
      <Bug pattern="SBSC_USE_STRINGBUFFER_CONCATENATION,*some more pattern*" />
      <OR>
       <Priority value="2" />
       <Priority value="3" />
      </OR>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

But this Filter did not work.
Do you know the correct configuration?

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Each Match is something to filter out. Try splitting the filter in two matches:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FindBugsFilters>
    <Match>      
      <Bug pattern="SBSC_USE_STRINGBUFFER_CONCATENATION,*some more pattern*" />
      <Priority value="2" />
    </Match>
    <Match>      
      <Bug pattern="SBSC_USE_STRINGBUFFER_CONCATENATION,*some more pattern*" />
      <Priority value="3" />
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, this does not work. Priority 2 warnings were excluded, but priority 3 warings not.