# Maven + FindBugs - fail on high-priority warning

Tags: java, maven, hudson, findbugs

I am using Maven and FindBugs on a large project. I would like to cause a maven build to fail if FindBugs yields any *high* priority errors. A simple parameter can be set within a pom.xml to fail on *errors* but I need it to fail on high priority warnings. Any suggestions would be huge!

Comment: Does Findbugs output some message in case such warning has been found?

Comment: Yes, they do. What are you thinking?

Comment: In our company we use TeamCity as our CI server and it has option to fail build if some message has been encountered in logs. Maybe there is something similar in Hudson. If so, you could use it =)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are already aware of the findbugs:check goal available for the plugin.
Setting the threshold configuration item to High should limit the goal to failing only on High priority issues.

Here is an example configuration snippet for your pom.xml

```
<build>
...
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>failing-on-high</id>
      <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <threshold>High</threshold>
        <onlyAnalyze>com.example.-</onlyAnalyze>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
</plugins>
...
</build>
```

In this snippet, I have limited analysis to packages beginning with 'com.example' and set the threshold to High, and configured the findbugs:check to run before the automated tests.

An example of this triggering a build failure:

```
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:2.4.0:findbugs (findbugs) @ channels ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
     [java] Warnings generated: 29
[INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< findbugs-maven-plugin:2.4.0:check (failing-on-high) @ channels <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:2.4.0:check (failing-on-high) @ pricing ---
[INFO] BugInstance size is 29
[INFO] Error size is 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See also: http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html for other configuration options you can include. You will probably want to include the xml report so that your CI server can capture it for reporting the failures easily, using the xmlOutput configuration.

Comment: Hmm...this is partially working. It looks like it is failing even when only normal priority errors are encountered. I will check the check-mojo doc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...say we forget Hudson - even if I run a `mvn clean install findbugs:check` with the above in my pom.xml, on a project with only low priority warnings, I get a build failure due to findbugs. Its like it is ignoring the threshold altogether.

Comment: One more thing: this may in fact be a bug in the Maven plugin (I'm nearly convinced) in which case the workaround is to build a filter file, and then try to use that (looking again at the check-mojo link for the appropriate option). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657336/findbugs-howto-ignore-priority-2-and-3-warnings